# AES Decryption & Encryption

Tags: c#, mysql, encryption, utf-8, ascii

I've incorporated this code to encrypt my data.
Unfortunately, there's always this Error:

> The input is not a valid Base 64 string because it contains a non-Base 64 character, more than two spaces, or an invalid character in the spaces.

This is my Code -->

```
    public static string IV = "abababababababab";  // 16 chars = 128 bytes
    public static string Key = "abababababababababababababababab";   // 32 chars = 256 bytes
    public static string Encrypt(string decrypted)
    {
        byte[] textbytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider encdec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        encdec.BlockSize = 128;
        encdec.KeySize = 256;
        encdec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        encdec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        encdec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        encdec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform icrypt = encdec.CreateEncryptor(encdec.Key, encdec.IV);

        byte[] enc = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(textbytes, 0, textbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        return Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string encrypted)
    {
        byte[] encbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
        AesCryptoServiceProvider encdec = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        encdec.BlockSize = 128;
        encdec.KeySize = 256;
        encdec.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Key);
        encdec.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
        encdec.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        encdec.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform icrypt = encdec.CreateDecryptor(encdec.Key, encdec.IV);

        byte[] dec = icrypt.TransformFinalBlock(encbytes, 0, encbytes.Length);
        icrypt.Dispose();

        return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(dec);
    }
```

This is my Login Form -->

```
        private void buttonlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs ex)
    {
        if (textboxusername.Text.Length < 2 || textboxpassword.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            FormMsbOk.Show("Username or Password is too short!","Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlConnection con;
            con = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string exists = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userlogin`.`userlogin` " +
                $"( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `username` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , `prename` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , `surname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , `emailadress` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(exists, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                string user = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxusername.Text);
                string pass = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxpassword.Text);
                string encusr = $"SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username='{user}';";
                string encpass = $"SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE password='{pass}';";

                string decusr = AesCrypt.Decrypt(encusr);
                string decpass = AesCrypt.Decrypt(encpass);

                if (decusr == textboxusername.Text && decpass == textboxpassword.Text)
                {
                    FormMsbOk.Show("You logged in successfully as user: " + textboxusername.Text, "Ok");
                    con.Close();
                    this.Hide();
                    var main = new FormMain();
                    main.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                    main.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    textboxusername.Clear();
                    textboxpassword.Clear();
                    FormMsbOk.Show("Error Username or password is wrong!", "Ok");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception nocon)
            {
                textboxusername.Clear();
                textboxpassword.Clear();
                FormMsbOk.Show("Can not open connection! " + nocon.Message,"Ok");
            }
```

And this is my Register Form -->

```
private void buttonregister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textboxusername.Text.Length < 2 || textboxpassword.Text.Length < 4)
        {
            FormMsbOk.Show("Username or Password is too short! " +
                "The minimum for the user name is 2 characters and for " +
                "the password is 4 characters. ", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlConnection con;
            con = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string exists = $"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userlogin`.`userlogin` " +
                $"( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `username` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , `prename` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , `surname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL , `emailadress` VARCHAR(64)" +
                $" NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;";
                MySqlCommand emdexists = new MySqlCommand(exists, con);
                emdexists.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string encusr = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxusername.Text);
                string encpass = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxpassword.Text);
                string encprename = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxprename.Text);
                string enclastname = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxlastname.Text);
                string encemail = AesCrypt.Encrypt(textboxemail.Text);
                string insert = $"INSERT INTO `userlogin`.`userlogin` " +
                    $"(`username`, `password`, `prename`, `surname`, `emailadress`) " +
                    $"VALUES ('" + encusr + "', '" + encpass + "', '" + encprename + "'," +
                    " '" + enclastname + "', '" + encemail + "');";
                MySqlCommand cmdinsert = new MySqlCommand(insert, con);
                cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                FormMsbOk.Show("Registriert", "Ok");
                textboxusername.Clear();
                textboxpassword.Clear();
                textboxprename.Clear();
                textboxlastname.Clear();
                textboxrepeat.Clear();
                textboxemail.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception nocon)
            {
                FormMsbOk.Show("Can not open connection! " + nocon.Message, "Ok");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Passwords should be hashed not encrypted, and always use SQL Parameters to create SQL not string concatenation

Comment: Look at what you’re giving to the Decrypt method. That should explain it. And do heed the advice about always hashing passwords, never encrypting them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That's not very helpful. Wouldn't you have a solution that has to do with improving the code?

Comment: @Henni What isn’t helpful? I pointed the exact point where the error is. You can check it and understand yourself what is wrong and fix it. It is simple when you look at four lines of code. If people spoon feed code for you there’s not much learning. Also I do suggest learning to use a debugger, it will help immensely in realizing what is wrong with your code every time you have problems

Comment: If you want more specific help: run the code in debug mode and have it break on exceptions and you catch the exact moment where the problem occurs. You can see what input you’re giving to the method and why it isn’t valid base64 as it expects.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Sorry, but I don't quite follow you. I am in training as an IT specialist and have not been programming for too long, so unfortunately I don't understand exactly what they mean by that. 
Would you please give me another tip which lines, for example?

Comment: You set variables user and pass and then give them to Decrypt. They are SQL clauses which should be sent to the database engine, not to Decrypt by themselves

Comment: I can't find the error @SamiKuhmonen.
I just tried another way but it didn't work either.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Can you edit my code please and add it as answer? I can’t see or read the error in the debug log :/

Comment: Let's see an input string that is 'invalid'.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `string decusr = AesCrypt.Decrypt(encusr);` and use a breakpoint on that line to see what the value of `encusr` is at that point.

You're passing a string containing an SQL query to the `AesCrypt.Decrypt` method which expects to be given an encrypted value to be decrypted. You probably want it to be processing the result of running that query, not the query itself.

Other tips:

1. `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done this, you don't need to worry about closing the connection, as exiting the using block will dispose the connection, which will call Close. And notice that it will close it even if your code throws an exception inside the block.
2. If you use string concatenation to construct a query, it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (and other problems): use SQL parameters instead.
3. As mentioned by others in the comments, it's good practice to store a hash of the password rather than an encryption of it. Encryption is a two way process which would allow someone to find out a password by decrypting it. A hash is a one-way, but repeatable process. Rather than trying to decrypt the stored password, you create the hash of the entered password and check whether the hash is the same as the stored hash of the actual password. But make sure you use [a salted hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983).

Comment: The debug point at the place "string decusr = AesCrypt.decrypt(encusr);" returns = null!
Could you help me to read the username and password from the database and the comparison?

Comment: Look at `encusr` not `decusr`, because that won't be set until this line has been completed.

Comment: Can you post a code example where I can check from an ID if the entered username and password value is the same as the AES secured code?

Comment: This is not a code authoring site, and we don't do "training". This is a problem solving site - you show us a problem that you're having, and we help you solve it. You'd be surprised how many questions on SO are in a "I've created a login screen" scenario like yours. Search for things, you will find the answers.

Comment: @Henni Here's a link with some basic information about using a salted hash... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649202(v=pandp.10)  Because I realised I didn't mention the word 'salt' in my answer, and [a hash without salt is not a good solution](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983).

Comment: That's okay. I have revised a large part of my code and have now solved the error.
The system now works perfectly without errors and problems! I will publish the source code on GitHub and post it here for everyone who would like to use it.